# Println not printing all my values - java

Tags: java

So, I'm an Absolut noob trying to learn Java so please be nice.
I'm trying to create a postage calculator, using a switch with if/if else inside. It's for an assignment in school so I have to use a switch.
Problem is that I can't get the println at the end of my cases to print all the values.
If anyone could take a look and point out my mistakes that would be really appreciated.

```
package inlämningsuppgift_2_porto_alysia_nonor;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Inlämningsuppgift_2_porto_Alysia_Nonor {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // Ledtext, presentation av menyval
        System.out.println("Beräkna ditt porto");
        System.out.println(" ");
        
        //user input, meny med val
        System.out.println("Önskar du skicka");
        System.out.println("1. Brev");
        System.out.println("2. Rekommenderat brev");
        System.out.println("3. Brev skicka lätt");       
        System.out.print("Ange ditt val: ");
        int brevVal = input.nextInt();
        
        //beräkning av porto
        switch (brevVal){
            case 1:
                brevVal = 1;
                System.out.print("Ange vikten i gram: ");
                double brevEttgram = input.nextDouble();
                
                    double porto;
                    int frimärken;
                    
                    if (brevEttgram <= 50){
                        porto = 11;
                        frimärken = 1;
                    
                    }
                    else if (brevEttgram <= 100){
                        porto = 22;
                        frimärken = 2;
                    
                    }
                    else if (brevEttgram <= 250){
                        porto = 44;
                        frimärken = 4; 
                    }
                    else if (brevEttgram <= 500){
                        porto = 66;
                        frimärken = 6; 
                    }
                    
                    else if (brevEttgram <= 1000){
                        porto = 88;
                        frimärken = 8; 
                    }
                    
                    else
                        porto = 110;
                        frimärken = 10; 
                        
            System.out.print("Ditt brev behöver " +frimärken+ " frimärken och det kommer kosta " +porto+ " kr");            
            break; 
            
            case 2:
                brevVal = 2;
                System.out.print("Ange vikten i gram: ");
                double rekBrevgram = input.nextDouble();
                
                    double prisFörfrimärkt;
                    double prisSkickadirekt;
                    
                    if (rekBrevgram <= 50){
                        prisFörfrimärkt = 92; 
                        prisSkickadirekt = 72;
                    
                    }
                    else if (rekBrevgram <= 100){
                        prisFörfrimärkt = 103;
                        prisSkickadirekt = 83;
                    
                    }
                    else if (rekBrevgram <= 250){
                        prisFörfrimärkt = 125;
                        prisSkickadirekt = 105; 
                    }
                    else if (rekBrevgram <= 500){
                        prisFörfrimärkt = 147;
                        prisSkickadirekt = 127; 
                    }
                    
                    else if (rekBrevgram <= 1000){
                        prisFörfrimärkt = 169;
                        prisSkickadirekt = 149; 
                    }
                    
                    else
                        prisFörfrimärkt = 191;
                        prisSkickadirekt = 171;
                        
            System.out.print("Du kan antingen skicka ditt brev med Pris för frimärkt, vilket kommer kosta " +prisFörfrimärkt+ " kr eller Skicka Direkt vilket kommer kosta " +prisSkickadirekt+ " kr");  
                
            break;    
                
            case 3:
                brevVal = 3;
                System.out.print("Ange vikten i gram: ");
                double skickaLättgram = input.nextDouble();
                
                System.out.print("Ange maxmåttet: ");
                double skickaLättmått = input.nextDouble();
                
                    double prisSkickalätt;
                    
                    if (skickaLättgram >= 2000 || skickaLättmått >= 90){     
                        System.out.print("Ditt paket är för stort eller tungt för att skickas som Brev Skicka lätt. Välj ett annat alternativ.");
                    }
                    else if (skickaLättgram <= 2000 && skickaLättmått <= 90){
                        prisSkickalätt = 95;
                    }
                    else {{
                    prisSkickalätt = 62;
                    }
                    System.out.print("Ditt paket går att skicka som ett Brev Skicka lätt. Portot kommer kosta " +prisSkickalätt+ " kr");
                    }
            break;    
                
            
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the input you are giving, what output are you getting and what output are you expecting?

Comment: `else porto = 110; frimärken = 10;` Java isn't Python and indentations don't matter. I think that you want curly braces around those assignments, no? `else `porto = 110; frimärken = 10; }`

Answer (score -1):

First : A variable's name should **never** (edit: by convention - even if some programming languages allow it) contain diacritics

Second : In your "case 3", you only print your values in the "else" statement, not in those cases:

```
    if (skickaLättgram >= 2000 || skickaLättmått >= 90) {} 
    else if (skickaLättgram <= 2000 && skickaLättmått <= 90) {}
```

Comment: thanks for responding. 
Any queses why 
System.out.print("Ditt brev behöver " +frimärken+ " frimärken och det kommer kosta " +porto+ " kr"); Thats on row 61
is only printing porto correctly but only prints the frimärke value from row 59?

Comment: re: *A variable's name should never contain diacritics*  Why?  Why should all programmers adhere to American ideas of what a valid letter is?

Comment: @AlysiaNonor
I think that you forgot to put curly braces around your else block, which will, in Java just consider the first statement as being part of "else", the other statement (frimärken = 10;) being executed whatever the conditions before return
-----
I edited my post a while ago to emphasize the convention aspect of it, but for my defense, I'd like to say that diacritics, unlike basic ASCII may differ based on the encoding one uses : it is not universally supported by all compilers (GCC for an example) - For Java, it is indeed allowed but it's a convention regarding older languages

Comment: This question isn't about older language conventions but about Java and Java only